# Replacing substring in second occurrence in prolog

Tags: string, recursion, replace, prolog

First of all, this is not a homework. I'm studying Computer Sciences in my home, to learn a little more alone.

I'm doing an excercise. It says like this:

> Construct a predicate called `replaceAtomsString/4` so that given
>       a string `s` as the first parameter, a number `N` as the second parameter,
>       and a pair of atoms `[g, h]` (list) as the third parameter, unify in a 
>       fourth parameter the replacement in the Nth apparition of `g` in `s` 
>       replacing it by `h`. Example:

```
replaceAtomsString (sAbbbsAbbasA, 2, [sA, cc], X) should result in

X = sAbbbccbbasA
```

So, my first approach was trying to build a list with the string, just like prolog do with every string. After all, i've built this code:

```
substitute(X, S, T, Y) :-
    append(S, Xt, X), % i.e. S is the first part of X, the rest is Xt
    !,
    substitute(Xt, S, T, Yt),
    append(T, Yt, Y).
substitute([Xh|Xt], S, T, [Xh|Yt]) :-
    substitute(Xt, S, T, Yt).
```

But it returns `false` on every attempt.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use `append/3` to break apart atoms, you probably need `atom_concat/3`.

Comment: In addition to Daniel's comment, your arguments seem a bit mixed up. According to your desired sample call, the second argument is a count or index of the substring you want to match. But your call to `append(S, Xt, X)` in your first clause treats `S` as a substring. I don't see any logic that deals with handling an index. Looks like you need to think through your code a bit more carefully.

Comment: That's the problem, i dont understand why it is mixed.

Comment: `atom_concat(Left, Right, LeftRight)` helps you, because you can stuff the thing you have (`sAbbbsAbbasA`) into the third argument and then it will break it into two pieces. Try it in the REPL: `atom_concat(Left, Right, sAbbbsAbbasA).`

Answer (score 1):

Since you need substantial work to get your code done, here is how to perform the task using the available libraries.

[sub_atom](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sub_atom/5)/5 it's a rather powerful predicate to handle atoms. Coupled with [call_nth](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call_nth/2)/2, the solution is straightforward and more general than what would result coding the loop around N.

```
replaceAtomsString(S,N,[G,H],X) :-
    call_nth(sub_atom(S,Before,_,After,G),N),
    sub_atom(S,0,Before,_,Left),
    sub_atom(S,_,After,0,Right),
    atomic_list_concat([Left,H,Right],X).
```

Example running your query, but leaving N to be computed:

```
?- replaceAtomsString(sAbbbsAbbasA, N, [sA, cc], X).
N = 1,
X = ccbbbsAbbasA ;
N = 2,
X = sAbbbccbbasA ;
N = 3,
X = sAbbbsAbbacc ;
false.
```